# Json array Result format and display

Tags: arrays, json, format

Hi I have got the following method which fetches the JSON data

```
$("#Result").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "SampleWebForm.aspx/FetchLibraryDetails",
                        data: "{}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                         // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                            $("#Result").text(msg.resources.description.title);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

**The JSON result from the call is as below**

```
LibraryData{
    "resources": {
        "description": {
            "title": "Getting started with the online library",
            "body": "The online library contains amazing resources and can seem overwhelming. This guide gives a very basic introduction. Over your years of study with us you will learn a lot more about resources and how to find and manage them.",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/files\/library\/imagecache\/node_standard\/web-journal%20shelves.JPG",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/node\/91194"
        },
        "items": [{
            "title": "Large-scale open innovation: open source vs. patent pools",
            "body": "Thierry Rayna (2010), 'Large-scale open innovation: open source vs. patent pools', International Journal of Technology Management, vol. 52, no. 3\/4, pp:477-0",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/libraryservices\/covers\/?id=0140-6736",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/libraryservices\/resource\/article:7477"
        },
        {
            "title": "Introduction to Library Services",
            "body": "A great introductory session that will explore the online library. You will know how to find information in your subject and be shown some key resources and services to help with your studies.",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/files\/library\/imagecache\/node_standard\/web-journal%20shelves.JPG",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/node\/97689"
        }]
    },
    "access": {
        "items": [{
            "title": "Large-scale open innovation: open source vs. patent pools",
            "body": "Thierry Rayna (2010), 'Large-scale open innovation: open source vs. patent pools', International Journal of Technology Management, vol. 52, no. 3\/4, pp:477-0",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/libraryservices\/covers\/?id=0140-6736",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/libraryservices\/resource\/article:7477"
        },
        {
            "title": "Getting started with the online library",
            "body": "The online library contains amazing resources and can seem overwhelming. This guide gives a very basic introduction. Over your years of study with us you will learn a lot more about resources and how to find and manage them.",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/files\/library\/imagecache\/node_standard\/web-journal%20shelves.JPG",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/node\/91194"
        }],
        "description": {
            "title": "Getting started with the online library",
            "body": "The online library contains amazing resources and can seem overwhelming. This guide gives a very basic introduction. Over your years of study with us you will learn a lot more about resources and how to find and manage them.",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/files\/library\/imagecache\/node_standard\/web-journal%20shelves.JPG",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/node\/91194"
        }
    },
    "search": {
        "items": [{
            "title": "Large-scale open innovation: open source vs. patent pools",
            "body": "Thierry Rayna (2010), 'Large-scale open innovation: open source vs. patent pools', International Journal of Technology Management, vol. 52, no. 3\/4, pp:477-0",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/libraryservices\/covers\/?id=0140-6736",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/libraryservices\/resource\/article:7477"
        },
        {
            "title": "Getting started with the online library",
            "body": "The online library contains amazing resources and can seem overwhelming. This guide gives a very basic introduction. Over your years of study with us you will learn a lot more about resources and how to find and manage them.",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/files\/library\/imagecache\/node_standard\/web-journal%20shelves.JPG",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/node\/91194"
        }],
        "description": {
            "title": "Getting started with the online library",
            "body": "The online library contains amazing resources and can seem overwhelming. This guide gives a very basic introduction. Over your years of study with us you will learn a lot more about resources and how to find and manage them.",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/files\/library\/imagecache\/node_standard\/web-journal%20shelves.JPG",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/node\/91194"
        }
    },
    "helpdesk": {
        "items": [{
            "title": "Large-scale open innovation: open source vs. patent pools",
            "body": "Thierry Rayna (2010), 'Large-scale open innovation: open source vs. patent pools', International Journal of Technology Management, vol. 52, no. 3\/4, pp:477-0",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/libraryservices\/covers\/?id=0140-6736",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/libraryservices\/resource\/article:7477"
        },
        {
            "title": "Getting started with the online library",
            "body": "The online library contains amazing resources and can seem overwhelming. This guide gives a very basic introduction. Over your years of study with us you will learn a lot more about resources and how to find and manage them.",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/files\/library\/imagecache\/node_standard\/web-journal%20shelves.JPG",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/node\/91194"
        }],
        "description": {
            "title": "Getting started with the online library",
            "body": "The online library contains amazing resources and can seem overwhelming. This guide gives a very basic introduction. Over your years of study with us you will learn a lot more about resources and how to find and manage them.",
            "image": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/files\/library\/imagecache\/node_standard\/web-journal%20shelves.JPG",
            "link": "http:\/\/www.testWebsite.com\/library\/node\/91194"
        }
    }
}
```

My Question

Basically I am getting a set of JSON data (as above) on to the "data" object.

While debugging I can see the whole json data in the "data" object and can write on to a div tag using “data.d”

But I want to display the data separately from the JSON result  Like

4 DIVs resources, access, search & helpdesk.

Under each of these I want to display the corresponding Description and items (each having title, body, image and link).

Answer (score 0):

You have several different options, you can loop through the json object and hand roll some html to do what you want.

or - a much better way would be to use a library that supports templates like Knockout or Angular

If all you need is templates I would go with something like Knockout

[Check out the Note 2 example - Using "foreach" option with named template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)

I personally like Angular, however it may be overkill for your situation

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your Object and append some HTML-Element with propertys or Key-Value-Pairs like:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  // do something

  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // do somthing else
  }
}
```

Comment: like Mark said, Angular does this very well with the ng-repeat directive